naudio input device receives no correct data
I want to record some sounds to a wave file on a windows 11 PC with Bitdefender.
So far I use this 2 methodes:

 private MMDevice SetCurrentDevice(DataFlow dataFlow, string deviceName)
 {
     var devices = m_deviceEnumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(dataFlow, DeviceState.Active);

     MMDevice selectedDevice = null;


     for (int i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++)
     {
         var device = devices[i];
         if (CompareDeviceNameStrings(device.DeviceFriendlyName, deviceName))
         {
             selectedDevice = device;

             if (dataFlow == DataFlow.Capture)
             {
                 m_currentMicIndex = i;
             }
             else
             {
                 m_currentSpeakerIndex = i;
             }

             
             MuteAllDevices(dataFlow);
             break;
         }
     }

     return selectedDevice;
 }

  public void Record(String strFile)
  {
      try
      {
          SetMicVolume(100);
          m_bIsRecording = true;

          m_strCurrentFile = strFile;
          m_WaveSource = new WaveIn();
          int waveInDevice = AudioDeviceCtrl.GetInstance().GetCurrentMicIndex();

          if (waveInDevice < 0)
          {
              SimpleLog.Error("No microphone device found.");
              return;
          }
          m_WaveSource.DeviceNumber = waveInDevice;

          WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(waveInDevice);            
          
          m_WaveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 2);

          m_WaveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(DataAvailable);
          m_WaveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(RecordingStopped);

          m_WaveFile = new WaveFileWriter(strFile, m_WaveSource.WaveFormat);

          m_WaveSource.StartRecording();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          SimpleLog.Error($"Recording failed: {ex.Message}");
      }
  }
  
 void DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
 {
             m_WaveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
             m_WaveFile.Flush();

             SimpleLog.Debug("bytecound: " + e.BytesRecorded.ToString() );
             int bytesToLog = Math.Min(e.BytesRecorded, 10); // Log first 10 bytes or fewer if less available
            string bufferSnippet = string.Join(", ", e.Buffer.Take(bytesToLog).Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
            SimpleLog.Debug("Buffer snippet: " + bufferSnippet);
 }

The Event is fired and I get Data but it's only 0x00 and 0xFF like I can see here:
bytecound: 17640
Buffer snippet: 00, 00, 00, 00, FF, FF, 01, 00, 00, 00
In the windows settings I can see that the correct capture device is reacting to ma voice and it seems that DataAvailable is receiving something but it's trash. During startup I have muted all capture devices to make sure that nothing else is receiving data. Bevor I start recording SetMicVolume(100); is unmuting the current device and set volume to 100. I checked the windows settings and saw that it worked
I checked in the soundsettings of windows if the right capture device gets unmuted and set to 100%
I checked BitDefender, it only logs the access to the mic but I saw nothing that it would block the access, but I'm not completely sure.
I also tried another microphone but the behaviour was the same.
I wondering about the logged bytecount number and the buffer snippet data.
I hope someone else can give me a hint what the reason could be
Oh maybe it's important, I had to switch my application from .net framework 4.8 to .net8.0 With 4.8 I had no problems. I just noticed that naudio seems to support .net6.0 Could this have some influence?

I encountered exactly the same issue a few days ago.
My Naudio WaveInEvent instance returned only 0xff, 0x00 and some 0x01 values which are for sure no real sound data input.
I've first suspected framework issues (used .Net standard 2) but I got the same issue with a .Net 6 test on Win10 and Win11 PCs.
Eventually I figured out the source: it was not Naudio!
As long as I had some breakpoints in my program I recieved those "empty" sound data blocks. But as soon as I removed all breakpoints everything is working fine!
